# How to query in MariaDB using custom translation

Tags: sql, mariadb

In the following table, I want to be able to query the column `first_name` by removing accents and translating specific characters:

| id | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nick |
| 2 | Νίκος |

for example I want the word `Νίκος` to be "translated" to `nikos` while querying, and have the following match both rows instead of only the first:

`select * from contact where first_name like "ni%"`

meaning I want a way to convert the letters in the following way:

`{ "Ν": "n", "ί": "i", "κ": "k", "ο": "o", "ς": "s" }`

this won't be according to any universal standard so this character matching will be custom

I am quite new with SQL (and MariaDB) so I'm not sure if that's even possible. I've tried looking but the closest I could find is collate, but from my limited understanding, I don't think it does what I want or I haven't figured out how to use it properly.

I also understand that doing this while querying might be a bit expensive but I don't want to have to duplicate "translated" rows in order to query those instead.

Comment: you need to write a huge nested Replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the translation matrix is static, you could use replace in a function

```
CREATE TABLE contact
    (`id` int, `first_name` varchar(5))
;
    
INSERT INTO contact
    (`id`, `first_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'nick'),
    (2, 'Νίκος')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE FUNCTION trans( name varchar(50)) RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN
  return (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name
  ,'ς', 's')
  ,'ο', 'o')
  ,'κ', 'k')
  ,'ί', 'i')
  ,'Ν', 'n'));

END
```

```
select * from contact where trans(first_name) like "ni%"
```

| id | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nick |
| 2 | Νίκος |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BiHzgq01)

Comment: It will be static yes, is there any issue with doing this for the whole alphabet? I mean it's not going to be pretty but I don't care as long as it doesn't have any serious performance issues if I have like 30 maybe 40 `replace`

Comment: you need to add all replaces as i did one by one, still this needs a lot of resources,   my opinion, save the converted directly in the database, and query the converted column with index it will be faster than doing replaces

Comment: got it, thanks! I might do that if I see it becomes very slow